# Invalid left-hand side in assignment nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey this has been driving me crazy. I have this code, and the desired objective is to create a Author with the properties given. I have everything such as mongodb compass and mongod running, and after this error i updated npm + node. Still an error.

**The code is here:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground')
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB...', err));

const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   bio: String,
   website: String,
})

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String
})

const Author = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema)

const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema)

async function createAuthor(name, bio, website) { 
  const author = new Author({
    name, 
    bio, 
    website 
  });

  const result = await author.save();
  console.log(result);
}

async function createCourse(name, author) {
  const course = new Course({
    name, 
    author
  }); 

  const result = await course.save();
  console.log(result);
}

async function listCourses() { 
  const courses = await Course
    .find()
    .select('name');
  console.log(courses);
}

createAuthor('Mosh', 'My bio', 'My Website');

// createCourse('Node Course', 'authorId')

// listCourses();
```

**And the given error is Here:**

```
|| (selector['mapreduce'] && selector.out = 'inline')) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/eesamunir/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/index.js:29:17
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be '===' instead of '=' for the operator?

Comment: Thats a syntax error of mongoose. try `npm install mongoose` to get the newest version, if the error still occurs report it

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks so much man! it worked!

Answer (score 1):

As the error does not occur in your code, it has to be one from mongoose. It looks like that SyntaxError was fixed already, so just get the new fixed version with:

```
  npm install mongoose
```